# how to search in the <body> of a document

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML with two `<a>` elements:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>
        <script>
            function onLoad() {
                var bodyLinks = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a");
                var msg = "There's "+bodyLinks.length
                        +" links in the body, of which the first one is: ["+bodyLinks[0].href+"].";
                console.log(msg);
            }
            window.onload = onLoad;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br/>
        <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">www.stackoverflow.com</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

One of the `<a>` elements is in the `<head>` element, the other in the `<body>`. Yet the above page upon loading writes on the console:

```
There's 2 links in the body, of which the first one is:  [http://www.google.com/].
```

What's more puzzling, changing `document.body.getElementsByTagName` to `document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName` produces exactly the same result. Do I understand right that `document.body` is then an alias for `document.documentElement` and does not actually point to the `<body>` element of the HTML?

Comment: You shouldn't have anchor tags in the head of the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first anchor is not in the head element.

- Anchors are not allowed within the head element
- The end tag for the head element is optional
- The start tag for the body element is optional

By trying to start an anchor in the head, you implicitly end the head element and start the body element.

The end tag for the head and start tag for the body are then invalid markup and are ignored.

Comment: *additionally `document.body !== document.documentElement`. The former references the `<body>` node while the latter references the `<html>` node.